# Support for Oracle Streams after 11g R2

Tags: database, oracle, replication, deprecated, oracle12c

I am looking for information about Oracle's plans for Streams (a data replication technology) going forward.  Will this continue to be supported in future releases?

Right now I only have this brief reference :

[Oracle Base Oracle 12C Articles](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/articles-12c.php)

Comment: As it hasn't been released yet you're effectively asking people to guess... which isn't going to very helpful to anyone.

Comment: @Ben Maybe, but I am asking for any clue (maybe a Oracle OW reference or any non-formal documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking about Oracle's [Statement of Direction for GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/statement-of-direction-gg-132120.pdf).  Specifically, the section on the future of Streams

> Oracle Streams continues to be supported but will not be enhanced to
>   support any new database features in future releases. This means that
>   Streams will continue to support exactly what it supports today (11.2)
>   in future releases. It also means that any new database features, data
>   types, or capabilities will not be supported by Streams. Customers who
>   want to take advantage of the new data types and features will need to
>   license Oracle GoldenGate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the Streams info that I need.